# Hidden field in detailsview - aspnet membership userID

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, boundfield

I have a little detailsview where i can add some data to my DB.

The detailsview's code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataSourceID="orderSqlDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" 
    Width="333px" DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" oniteminserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" 
                onprerender="DetailsView1_PreRender">
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userid" HeaderText="Azonosító" 
            SortExpression="userid" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Mennyiség (kg)" 
            SortExpression="quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mit rendel" SortExpression="Mit rendel">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ordertypeDropDownList" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="ordertypeDDLSqlDataSource" DataTextField="name" 
                    DataSource='<%# Bind("ordertype") %>'
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ordertype") %>'
                    DataValueField="ID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ordertypeDDLSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dotnetConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [ID] FROM [product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" CancelText="Mégsem" 
            InsertText="Elküld" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Here is the code behind for the page_load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            string userID = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
            ((TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = userID;
        }
    }
```

As you can see i fill the first boundfield from the page_load.
The problem is that the first boundfield (userid, or in my native language "azonosító") is important because of the database, but i don't want to let the user see his/her userid.
If i make the boundfield hidden (visible=false), it won't be reachable with the code in the page_load.
How can i bound the current userID to that field, when the field is hidden, or how can i get this work without boundfield for the ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user doesn't need to know or interact with the value you are inserting, then it is quite easy to inject parameter values into the insert call that the `DetailsView` sends to your datasource control.  Just use the `DetailsView.Inserting` event `DetailsViewInsertEventArgs` parameter as shown.

Code:

```
    protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            string userID = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
            e.Values.Add("userid", userID);
        }
    }
```

As you might expect, this method makes the BoundField completely unnecessary :)

Comment: Nice solution! Exactly what i need, and i learned something new as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Template Field and place a label and bind it with userid. You can access the label in your codebehind irrespective of it is invisible.

```
<asp:DetailsView   runat="server"  ID="dv" >
<Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("userid") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView> 

// In your code behind 
string userid = ((Label)dv.Rows[0].FindControl("lb")).Text(); // give the correct index
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but there's no reason to store the userid value in the DetailsView at all, based on the question posed.  See my answer for more...

Comment: Thanks Janjua, your solution is good as well, but it needs more magic because of the FindControl, and i like the easy way better. Anyway thank you too!

Comment: @pseudocoder yeah you are right, I saw your solution, it is much better then my solution. +1

Comment: @Waqar I changed the last line of code to use Text() method on the Label instead of ToString() - I belive that is what you ment. also +1  as your approach could be used in some situations